# Show an anchor only if user is logged in *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have an item in LocalStorage and based on if that item exists or not I want to show an anchor (Log Out) on my NavBar. Right now my line looks something like this:

```
<a href='#' *ngIf='!loggedIn' (click)='logOut()'>Log Out</a>
```

where `loggedIn` is a variable in the typescript file which gets the item.

```
public loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
```

Everything works fine on the login page, but after I log in the anchor is still not showing. Any solutions?

Comment: show your code, so we can get idea.

Comment: Can you show what value(s) you assign to `loggedIn`?

Comment: public loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

Comment: If `loggedIn` indicates the user is logged in then it would be true when you log in so `!loggedIn` would return false and it does not show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `loggedIn` is initialized once when your application starts. It does not listen to changes of the LocalStorage though. You need to create an event that updates the variable.

One way would be working with `Observables`:

You could create an `AuthService`, that has the methods `login()`, `logout()` and a public Observable variable `isLoggedIn$`.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {
  public isLoggedIn$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === 'true';
    this.isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(isLoggedIn);
  }

  login() {
    // logic
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(true);
  }

  logout() {
    // logic
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(false);
  }
}
```

When either `login` or `logout` is called, you `emit` a value to your `isLoggedIn$` Observable. You can then read the value of your Observable with the async pipe:

Inject the `AuthService` in your component:

```
constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}
```

Use it in your template:

```
<a href='#' *ngIf='authService.isLoggedIn$ | async' (click)='logOut()'>Log Out</a>
```

Have a look at this working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auth-login-logout?embed=1&file=src/app/auth.service.ts).

Comment: Also the logic error of `!loggedIn` assuming the var indicates that user is logged in and assuming the var is not updated when user logs in

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and answer but it's still not working for me. I mean it does the same behavior that I had before with my code.

Comment: Have you looked at the Stackblitz?

Comment: It does work in the Stackblitz, so there must be something different in your code. Note that you have to call `this.authService.logout()` in your `logOut()` method.

Comment: Also, the default state is logged out. So first you need to call `this.authService.login()` and then your button should show.

Comment: I did that. And I fixed it, I forgot to add something in the app.module. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul *ngIf="userCheck; else not_found" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a (click)="logout()" href="/">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<ng-template #not_found>
    // do anything
</ng-template>
```

If the user is logged in then `userCheck` is `true` otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 0):

more simply is using a getter

```
get loggedIn()
{
    return localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.ts` file

`authCheck() {
   return this.service.isAuthenticated();
 }`

where :

`service` is your service to check the authentication based on your localStorage and the function return `true` or `false`

then in your `html` :

`<ng-container *ngIf="authCheck(); then authenticatedTemplate; else unauthenticatedTemplate"></ng-container>`

`<a #authenticatedTemplate (click)='logOut()'>Log Out</a>`